# How to multiple class add on contact form 7 submit button

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

When i add bootstrap button class, like..

```
[submit class:btn btn-main btn-lg "Send"]
```

on browser i see it show only one class add.

```
<input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit btn" >
```

I need others 2 class add also Help Me..

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you need to add the class attribute to each one.

Try this instead:

```
[submit class:btn class:btn-main class:btn-lg "Send"]
```

Comment: The extra space would break the code in:  "class: btn-main"

Comment: but not remove default class. how to do it?

Comment: It adds `wpcf7-submit` instead of `submit`, Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 24):

Also CF7 used to have bug: if you put "class:" after "Send" nothing is added.

Comment: 2018-07-18 latest version still has this issue.

Comment: Bug or feature, but it's true now. Though, it should be comment, not answer.

Answer (score 4):

Have also just discovered if you put classes after a placeholder it doesn't work for some reason but putting it before does:

```
[text* your-name class:ast-col-xs-12 class:ast-col-sm-12 class:ast-col-md-6 class:ast-col-lg-6 placeholder "e.g. Joe Bloggs"]
```